# Get specific Version (@Label) for an old version tree

Tags: get, tfs-power-tools

I'm having some problem to get a specific Label version for an old tree path (moved, renamed, etc..) in TFS2008.

The problem I have is the following:

I renamed and moved some portion of tree version files and folder and now I'm not able to get a specific version from a specific Label. This Label was applied on the old tree path, and when I get specific version (with overwrite options checked) appear "Not downloaded" on the Latest column and I'm not able to work on the old baseline (labelled files and folder).
There is the way to get specific version in a custom target path?
The TFPT are helpful to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is get specific version Label on the project root, so the old tree version path is proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Nicola Celiento: I was about to post this as new question when I saw your question and answer, which have also worked for me.

I had a branch called $/MyProject/Dev/OldName, which was renamed to $/MyProject/Dev/NewName in May 2015. I now want to get all the files for this branch as of April 2014 (before the branch rename), but I can't work out how to do this. So far I have tried:

Creating a new workspace mapped to $/MyProject/Dev/NewName. Do Get Specific Version on $/MyProject/Dev/NewName, set Type to Date as of April 2014, set Overwrite writeable files and Overwrite all files. This results in the message: "All files are up to date. No files were updated because the requested file versions were previously downloaded. To force an update, use the "Get Specific Version" command with the "Overwrite all...) option checked." This message is odd because it is telling me to do precisely what I have done to get the message! In Source Control Explorer all files have a status of Not downloaded.

From the command line, do a get using the new branch name (does not work - no files in workspace):

C:\Workspace>tf get $/MyProject/Dev/NewName /version:D"2014-04-08 21:00:00" /overwrite /force /recursive
All files are up to date.

From the command line, do a get using the old branch name (also does not work - no files in workspace):

C:\Workspace>tf get $/MyProject/Dev/OldName /version:D"2014-04-08 21:00:00" /overwrite /force /recursive
No appropriate mapping exists for $/MyProject/Dev/OldName.

Changed my workspace to map to the old branch $/MyProject/Dev/OldName, and then repeated the previous get (also does not work - no files in workspace):

C:\Workspace>tf get $/MyProject/Dev/OldName /version:D"2014-04-08 21:00:00" /overwrite /force /recursive
C:\Projects:
Getting OldName

Using View History on individual files, I can see the files definitely existed at April 2014, and I can also see their contents, I just can't get them for that date (but I can get them OK after the branch rename).

Based on Nicola Celiento's answer the solution for me was to Get Specific Version on the root $/MyProject/Dev project. This got all the branches below $/MyProject/Dev, including the old $/MyProject/Dev/OldName that I wanted.